# JerseyUriBuilder query value encoding behavior changing in release 2.20

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0, uribuilder

`JerseyUriBuilder` encoding behavior changes in release 2.20. I detected this for URIs where a value in the query string part is '*'. Up to version 2.19 of the jersey-common library, there is no encoding happening, starting with 2.20 it gets encoded.

Is this a bug or a bugfix or just a switch between two valid results?

UPDATE

[According to the bug report](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2469?jql=text%20~%20%22jerseyuribuilder%22) linked in peeskillet's comment they fixed a bug in order to adhere to [the UriBuilder API](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html).

Comment: [This might be it](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2469?jql=text%20~%20%22jerseyuribuilder%22), though I was too lazy to read the whole thing :-)